# Ant - создание Jar с библиотеками внутри

Tags: ant, java

Что хочется сделать с помощью Apache Ant:

1. Создать 1 jar файл
2. Внутри него такая структура

   /lib/ <- сюда складываем все библиотеки  
   /META-INF/ <- здесь указываем Main-Class  
   /com/... <- скомпилированные классы  
   /тут файлы-конфиги

Возможно ли так сделать, если да, то как сложить все библиотеки которые находятся в разных папках в папку lib + при вызове

```
java -jar name.jar
```

эти библиотеки оказывали в classpath этого jar-ника
Спасибо.

Сделал так, но он складывает все классы в рут jar-ника (вместе с папками)

```
<jar destfile="${build.dir}/out/name.jar">
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.class"/>
            </fileset>
            <zipfileset dir="${lib.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            </zipfileset>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="mypackage.myClass" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю у вас два вопроса:

1. как сложить jar-ники в папку lib/ внутри другого jar. Это достигается при помощи аттрибута prefix у [zipfileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html)
2. как сделать так, чтобы при запуске java -jar name.jar то что в lib попадало в classpath. Этого можно достичь при помощи [one jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/), если не хочется возиться, причем тогда первая часть вопроса отпадает сама собой, или вручную при помощи [Jar class loader](https://github.com/kamranzafar/JCL/)

Answer (score 1):

Вроде бы как это нельзя сделать напрямую. Вам придётся специально заготавливать директорию в build, которая точно описывает содержимое jar'а.. заполнить её с помощью mkdir, copy, etc, а потом одним ударом запаковать jar'ом.